# Node.js and eslint disagree on "use strict"

Tags: node.js, strict, eslint

ESLint tells me that I do not need `"use strict"` at the top of my index.js file (it's a simple server like the 6-line one on https://nodejs.org/en/about/). Apparently all node modules are already in strict mode. Makes sense.

However, running `node index.js` gets me a "SyntaxError: [let] not supported outside strict mode." *does* run with the "redundant" `"use strict"` pragma.

Why the inconsistency? Shouldn't node know that this node module is indeed strict by default? Could this be due to some simple misconfiguration of node, ESLint, or my IDE?

Comment: You can run node with the `--use-strict` flag

Comment: ESLint is "wrong", but configurable: `/*eslint strict:0*/`.

Comment: That does it, @ExplosionPills! Thanks. Why not make it an answer and win a few points?

Comment: @Amit Thanks Amit. Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ESLint makes its own decisions about what it considers to be valid or invalid warnings or errors. You have to treat everything that eslint/jslint/jshint says as advisory on top of everything else. According to someone somewhere their suggestions are optimal and perfectly valid.

That being said, you do have some options to suppress this specific warning:

- Use `eslint` flags in comments in the code
- Run `eslint` with configuration to specify this flag
- Use the `--use-strict` flag when running `node`

The specific reason about why you get this warning has to do with the fact that the default node interpreter as it stands is not fully ES6-ready. For example, in node 4 you cannot use `let` outside of strict mode even though `let` is an ES6 keyword.

Comment: Found official documentation of this at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/3UXNCkAU8Es. Basically, node currently requires strict mode for ES6 block scoping features (`let`, `const`) for backward compatibility reasons. Some time in the future, the --use-strict flag won't be required for `let`. It's a transitory annoyance, which makes it more bearable.